# DJANGO | No existe el cursor «_django_curs_13944_1»

Tags: python, django, django-models

El siguiente modelo me da el siguiente error en el admin al crear un dispositivo (Si en vez de la `ForeignKey` hago mediante `choice`, no devuelve ningún error):

Errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from station.models import Station
from instalacion.models import Instalacion
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords


class TipoDispositivo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tipo dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tipos de dispositivos'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create your models here.
class Dispositivo(models.Model):
    tipo_dispositivo = models.ForeignKey(TipoDispositivo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    DEVICE_COM_CHOICE = (
        ('0','Radio Analógica'),
        ('1','Radio Digital'),
    )
    comunicacion_dispositivo = models.CharField('ComunicacionDispositivo', max_length=1, choices=DEVICE_COM_CHOICE,null=True, blank=True)
    marca = models.CharField('Marca',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    modelo = models.CharField('Modelo',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    disp_numserie = models.CharField('NºSerie',max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    dispositivoPadre =  models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)        
    instalacion = models.ForeignKey(Instalacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    observaciones = models.TextField('Observaciones',null=True, blank=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dispositivos'
        ordering = ['instalacion']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + ' - ' + self.marca + ' - ' + self.modelo
```

Archivo `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Dispositivo
from .models import TipoDispositivo


class TipoDispositivoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'name',
    )
admin.site.register(TipoDispositivo,TipoDispositivoAdmin)

class DispositivoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'tipo_dispositivo',
        'marca',
        'modelo',
        'disp_numserie',
        'ip_dispositivo',
    )

admin.site.register(Dispositivo,DispositivoAdmin)
```

Comment: Pero ¿bajo qué circunstancia te arroja ese error? Eso no dice mucho. ¿Simplemente cuando levantas la aplicación?, ¿cuándo intentas hacer un query desde alguna vista? Según la URL de tu error parece ser así. No olvides incluir esa parte del código.

Comment: Siempre dispuesto a ayudar César. Gracias. Eso me sucede en el administrador al crear un dispositivo. Si hago mediante un CHOICE funciona bien, si pongo FOREINGNKEY como en el ejemplo, devuelve ese error. Un saludo.

Comment: Ya veo, en todo caso, ¿puedes publicar el contenido total de tu models.py?

Comment: Ya he publicado el contenido "casitotal".

Answer (score 1):

Al ver tu codigo puedo ver la logica se contradice en gran manera ****str****.

```
    instalacion = models.ForeignKey(Instalacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
```

```
   def __str__(self):
        return str(self.instalacion) + ' - ' + self.marca + ' - ' + self.modelo
```

El campo ForeignKey, tiene los valores **null=True, blank=True**, esto quiere decir que no son obligatorios, pero mas abajo en ****str**** haces una consulta de un objecto que puede no existir.

Pero esto deberia de devolver un None - Marca.

Igualmente es bueno que agregues a tu pregunta el código de

```
from instalacion.models import Instalacion
```

Que puede ser el origen del problema.

---

Con el código que muestras la única solución que puedo darte es que modifiques el **str** por algo como esto.

```
   def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + ' - ' + self.marca + ' - ' + self.modelo
```

Comment: Lo de "from instalacion.models import Instalacion" ya estaba puesto. Por algún motivo dice que no hay relación entre DIspositivo y TipoDispositivo. ¿Qué sucede? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al borrar las filas existentes y crearlas tras crear el ForeignKey funciona bien. Parece que al tener anteriormente algunos valores creados mediante CHOICE, al modificar columna a ForeignKey devolvía error:

Archivo: models.py

```
from django.db import models
from station.models import Station
from instalacion.models import Instalacion
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords


class TipoDispositivo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tipo dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tipo de dispositivos'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create your models here.
class Dispositivo(models.Model):
    tipo_dispositivo = models.ForeignKey(TipoDispositivo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dispositivos'
        ordering = ['instalacion']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk) + ' - ' + self.marca + ' - ' + self.modelo + ' - ' + str(self.disp_numserie)
```

Comment: Recuerda siempre hacer las migraciones después de modificar valores en los modelos.